# How Can I Use This JavaScript Code in Unit Tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a basic app where you click on an image ,and it changes the src attribute for a video in an iframe. I'm wondering how I can unit test thing. I'm using karma and gulp to run the tests. Inside of an "it" test case I try to call a function, for example, changeIframeSrc, but my test runner always gives the error, "the variable changeIframeSrc is not defined". What's the best way to "import" vanilla javascript so that's it's available inside the unit tests?

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body class="background" onload="onLoad()">

<img id="bg-image" src="img/right.png">


<div>
    <a href="javascript:fd.navigationExitItem();" id="exit-text">
        < Exit Videos
    </a>
</div>

<iframe id="video-iframe" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/32342452" width="552" height="331" frameborder="0"
        webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div id="video-description">Video Description</div>

<img src="img/thumbnail1.png" width="180px" height="174px" id="first" onclick="thumbnailClicked(this)">
<img src="img/thumbnail2.png" width="180px" height="174px" id="second" onclick="thumbnailClicked(this)">
<img src="img/thumbnail3.png" width="180px" height="174px" id="third" onclick="thumbnailClicked(this)">
<img src="img/thumbnail4.png" width="180px" height="174px" id="fourth" onclick="thumbnailClicked(this)">
<img src="img/thumbnail5.png" width="180px" height="174px" id="fifth" onclick="thumbnailClicked(this)">
<img src="img/thumbnail6.png" width="180px" height="174px" id="sixth" onclick="thumbnailClicked(this)">
<img src="img/thumbnail7.png" width="180px" height="174px" id="seventh" onclick="thumbnailClicked(this)">

<!--<script href="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="data.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<!--<script src="jquery.js"></script>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     document.getElementById('video-iframe').src = dataArray["first"].url;
     document.getElementById('video-description').innerHTML = dataArray["first"].description;
});

function onLoad() {

}

function thumbnailClicked(element) {
  console.log("Thumbnail clicked: " + element.id);
  changeIframeSrc(element.id);
}

function changeIframeSrc(id) {

     var newVideoUrl = "";
     var newVideoTitle = "";
     var newVideoDescription = "";

     newVideoDescription = dataArray[id].description;
     newVideoUrl = dataArray[id].url;

     document.getElementById('video-iframe').src = newVideoUrl;
     document.getElementById('video-description').innerHTML = newVideoDescription;
}
```

data.js:

dataArray = [];
dataArray["first"] = {'url': 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/1231434', 'description': 'a video'};
dataArray["second"] = {'url': 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/43238313', 'description': 'something'};

})();

script.spec.js:

```
require('./script')
describe('the script', function() {
     it('should do this', function() {
          changeIframeSrc("first");
     })


})
```

And the tests always output: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: changeIframeSrc"

https://jsfiddle.net/14bmcLfb/

Answer (score 0):

As you state that you are using Karma, the best approach would be for you to list the javascript files the tests depend on in the "files" array of the Karma configuration file:

```
files = [
  '../pathToFile/script.js',
  //other dependencies
  '../pathToFile/script.spec.js'
]
```

Also I don't think the RequireJS syntax you're using is correct for this situation, "require('./script')" [would be used within a defined module](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html). For this sort of situation you would need to use the functions defined in the file within a callback function as the process of fetching the file would be asynchronous:

```
require(['./script'], function(script) {
 describe(...
});
```

Comment: I added 'script.js' to the files array in karma.conf.js, but I when I run the test I still get the error, "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: changeIframeSrc" :'(

Comment: Try setting the "singleRun" property in the Karma config file to false, you can then start Karma, navigate to http://localhost:9876/debug.html (or as configured in the config file) and then press debug to run the tests in debug mode. Using your browser developer tools you can check that script.js has been loaded and inspect what's available in the scope at the point the error is occurring. By the way the order in which the files are listed in the files array is the order in which they are loaded, so script.js needs to come first, just in case.